# How to write a file to the desktop in python?

Tags: python

When I make this code into an executable the function of writing a file works, but it writes to a random directory. I'm not sure how to get it to write to my desktop, like it did when it was a regular python file.

Here is my code,

```
def write():
        print('Creating a new file')

        name = raw_input('Enter a name for your file: ')+'.txt'  # Name of text file coerced with +.txt

        try:
            file = open(name,'w')   # Trying to create a new file or open one
            file.close()

        except:
            print('Something went wrong! Cannot tell what?')
            sys.exit(0) # quit Python
```

Comment: specify the full path for the file

Comment: Python will write to the current directory if not otherwise specified.

Comment: "Desktop" depends on  your operating system and/or window manager.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the path you want to save to. Furthermore, make use of `os.path.join` ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html)) to put the path and filename together. You can do something like this:

```
from os.path import join
def write():
        print('Creating a new file')
        path = "this/is/a/path/you/want/to/save/to"
        name = raw_input('Enter a name for your file: ')+'.txt'  # Name of text file coerced with +.txt

        try:
            file = open(join(path, name),'w')   # Trying to create a new file or open one
            file.close()

        except:
            print('Something went wrong! Cannot tell what?')
            sys.exit(0) # quit Python
```

Comment: What is the point of the try and except block?

Comment: @ZacharyChiodini - I stuck with the OP's original code which already has that `try/except`. As to the point? it depends. In this case it seems like the application wants to fail on any exception that could raise and just give a "generic" output to the user. Whether it is helpful or not is a different discussion. Similarly, one can ask why not have a more narrow exception (e.g. only catch `OSError`) and provide more context in the message? Or if still using a broad exception, why not analyze the exception object that is raised and output more context to the user?

Answer (score 0):

It is not writing into a random directory. It is writing into current directory, that is the directory you run it from. If you want it to write to a particular directory like your desktop you either need to add the path to the file name or switch the current directory. The first is done with

```
name = os.path.join('C:\Users\YourUser\Desktop', name)
```

the second is done with

```
os.chdir('C:\Users\YourUser\Desktop')
```

Or whatever the path to your desktop is.

Comment: You might also want to check if the user already appended path information to the file name in the input, like what if someone enters "C:\Windows\System32\rundll.exe" at the prompt.